# The property '$id' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.DirectoryServices.PasswordProfile'

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am unable to create a User using the code below. I recieve the following error:

> The property '$id' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.DirectoryServices.PasswordProfile'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.

```
Microsoft.Graph.PasswordProfile pf = new Microsoft.Graph.PasswordProfile
{
    ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
    Password = password
};

Microsoft.Graph.User newUser = new Microsoft.Graph.User
{
    Id = "",
    PasswordProfile = pf,
    Department = user.Department,
    DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
    GivenName = user.GivenName,
    JobTitle = user.JobTitle,
    AccountEnabled = true,
    MailNickname = user.MailNickname.Replace(" ", "").Replace(",", "").Replace("-", ""),
    MobilePhone = user.MobilePhone,
    OfficeLocation = user.OfficeLocation,
    PreferredLanguage = "en",
    Surname = user.Surname,
    Country = "US",
    UsageLocation = "US",
    OnPremisesImmutableId = user.OnPremisesImmutableId,
    UserPrincipalName = user.UserPrincipalName
};

int retrycount = 0;
retry:
    try
    {

        User createdUser = await graphClient.Users.Request().AddAsync(newUser);
        return createdUser.Id;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
```

Comment: Just remove the `Id` property. There's no need to specify it.

Comment: still same error, this code is working fine from test method , not for web app, which is using Azure AD authentication. maybe some library issue?

Comment: In my project i'm doing the same creating a user in Azure AD but i use this for the User: `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient.User`

Comment: Have you tried creating the `PasswordProfile`  inline (`PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile { ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true, Password = "password-value" },`)?

Comment: this code is in a class library when I use this library with the Front end using OKTA, this is working fine, even in test Function it is working fine. but when I try to use this library with Frontend using Azure AD Authentication, this throw exception.

Comment: @mab Code without id looks good. Once id has been removed the error should not appear. Are you sure is the same? If it's not then share it here.